# Problems with seasonplot() in R

Tags: r, plot

I've been working with some different sets of data that are time series and I just recently noticed that when I used `seasonplot`, it's assigning the wrong years to some of the plots. Here's data and what's happening.

```
library(forecast) #version 6.1
output <- read.csv("H:/Forecasting/data/cat1.csv", header = T)
data <- ts(output[, 3], frequency = 12, start = c(2008, 8))
data
#       Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
# 2008                                     579  388  921  575  647
# 2009  461 1461 2045 2684 2133 1697 1359 1053 1580 1197 1191 1231
# 2010  532 1023 1896 1111 1734 1204 1258 1190 1520 1635 1532 1539
# 2011 1127 1036 1561 1630 1437 1939 1659 1437 1443 1782  968 1245
# 2012 1110 1417 1965 2051 2204 2594 2075 2061 3539 4976 4922 4274
# 2013 3779 5031 5376 7449 6064 5513 5912 6472 5740 6351 4715 3226
# 2014 4523 4418 4305 6795 6331 6264 6666 7047 6049 7033 5343 5299
# 2015 5233 4952 5366 5897 5548 6928 

dput(data)

structure(c(579L, 388L, 921L, 575L, 647L, 461L, 1461L, 2045L, 
2684L, 2133L, 1697L, 1359L, 1053L, 1580L, 1197L, 1191L, 1231L, 
532L, 1023L, 1896L, 1111L, 1734L, 1204L, 1258L, 1190L, 1520L, 
1635L, 1532L, 1539L, 1127L, 1036L, 1561L, 1630L, 1437L, 1939L, 
1659L, 1437L, 1443L, 1782L, 968L, 1245L, 1110L, 1417L, 1965L, 
2051L, 2204L, 2594L, 2075L, 2061L, 3539L, 4976L, 4922L, 4274L, 
3779L, 5031L, 5376L, 7449L, 6064L, 5513L, 5912L, 6472L, 5740L, 
6351L, 4715L, 3226L, 4523L, 4418L, 4305L, 6795L, 6331L, 6264L, 
6666L, 7047L, 6049L, 7033L, 5343L, 5299L, 5233L, 4952L, 5366L, 
5897L, 5548L, 6928L), .Tsp = c(2008.58333333333, 2015.41666666667, 
12), class = "ts")

seasonplot(data, ylab = "Units Sold", year.labels = TRUE, year.labels.left = TRUE,
           labelgap = 0.8, col = 1:20, pch = 15, lwd = 3)
```

But it assigns some of the years incorrectly on the labels.  The most recent year should be 2015, but it's 2014.  It looks like the problem starts from 2012 to 2013.

This is the output:
[image]

Comment: When I paste in the data from above that I included from using dput, I don't get an error.  But when I go back and load the data from my file, I get the same error as before.  I loaded both separately and they look identical when I compare them, and when I used str()